# before defadvice not executing before the function?

Tags: emacs, elisp

[I apologize for the poor title, but couldn't come up with a better one.]

[bin chen](https://plus.google.com/110954683162859211810/posts/He1aCoQUYZy) asked on Google+:

> How to input relative path of (buffer-file-name) in minibuffer after `M-!` in #emacs?

I thought if the `buffer-file-name` is saved in a register, it should be accessible by invoking `insert-register` (<kbd>C-x r i</kbd>) while at the `shell-command` prompt.

```
(defun save-buffer-file-name-in-register ()
    (set-register ?F (buffer-file-name))
    (set-register ?D (file-name-directory buffer-file-name)))

(defadvice shell-command (before save-buffer-file-name)
  "Save buffer-file-name to register F before running shell-command"
  (save-buffer-file-name-in-register))

(ad-activate 'shell-command)
```

When I invoke `shell-command` (<kbd>M-!</kbd>) followed by `insert-register` (<kbd>C-x r i</kbd>), I get the error message: `Register does not contain any text`.

But when I run `list-registers` I do see that the registers `F` and `D` are set with the appropriate values. If I run the `shell-command` again, I can access the values from the registers previously saved.

Is it possible that the registers are being set too late for the first time? How can I fix the code to do what I want?

**Edit**: Changed `around` to `before` (Thanks to @phils)

Answer (score 2):

n.b. You have defined `around` advice, not `before` advice.

Around advice acts as a wrapper, and must include the token `ad-do-it` to execute the code of the function it is wrapping.

You have effectively replaced the body of the `shell-command` function with a call to `save-buffer-file-name-in-register`

As to your main question, I'd need to check the documentation, but I suspect that because the arguments to the advised function are available to advice, the original function's `interactive` declaration probably executes before the advice does, which would explain why your register values are not visible at the interactive shell-command prompt.

(If the `around` in the above code is indeed what you were using, the fact that you were still being prompted for a shell command would seem to verify this sequence.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was playing with both `around` and `before`, and "around" in the above code was the result of a incorrect paste from my emacs buffer. The version I actually tried and wanted to ask about was the "before" version.

Answer (score 2):

When the interactive form runs, your advice hasn't executed yet. See: this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233487/emacs-emacs-lisp-can-i-insert-advice-before-interactive-form-or-how-to-intelli)

You need to specify an interactive form in your advice that redefines the original if you want to stick with this approach.  However, this approach is a little fancy-pants for the sake of fancy-pants-ness.

Just define your own interactive function which does what you want without registers.

```lisp
(defun insert-cur-dir ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((dir-name (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name (window-buffer (minibuffer-selected-window))))))
    (insert (or dir-name ""))))

(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-c i") 'insert-cur-dir)
```

---

An alternative, but way awesomer approach is to use [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/).

Comment: Thanks for your response and link to the other question. Could you elaborate on why you think it is *fancy-pants for the sake of fancy-pants-ness*? I am not proficient in elisp, nor the right way of doing things. I thought `defadvice` was the perfect way to accomplish it with least amount of code, and without defining additional keybindings.

Comment: `defadvice` is a last resort solution.  If you want to stick to your original approach (i.e. put value into register), it would be quite straight forward to make your own command that calls `shell-command` instead of advising it.  Also commands typically don't make heavy use of registers.